# Laravel 5.3 and Redis (predis) - autoincrement hash and delete hash `row`

Tags: laravel-5, redis, predis

I've been flirting with Redis for a while now.

I've watched these [series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_jA39Uayak) some time ago and they were awesome. I've been through some of the documentation and the mentioning of the [Time complexity](http://redis.io/commands/scan) of the queries blew me away, this is something that's rarely mentioned in web materials but is of huge importance for app building.

Anyhow I'm trying to make my app use the Redis on the consumer end so the users can fetch the data as fast as possible.

So I'm trying to save some objects to hash as:

```
$redis->hmset("taxi_car", array(
  "brand" => "Toyota",
  "model" => "Yaris",
  "license number" => "RO-01-PHP",
  "year of fabrication" => 2010,
  "nr_stats" => 0)
```

as found [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-redis-in-php-using-predis/) and this works nicely.

However I can't find a way to delete the whole entry anywhere.
Did I get this hash thing wrong?

Following this example I would like to delete the entry with given `licence number`. All I could find is how to delete the licence number from the object:

```
$redis->hdel("taxi_car", "license number");
```

and can't figure out how to delete the whole hash `row` (please do correct with proper word for row here).

Another problem here is that it seems this only allows me to save a single `taxi_car` in the Redis. How do I set the UUID so I can have multiple Taxi cars?

I'm going to play with this a bit, any help is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a key of any type, Hash included, call the Redis [`DEL`](http://redis.io/commands/del) command.

To have multiple keys, give them different names, e.g. `taxi_car:1`, `taxi_car:2` etc.